# Cambio de valores en base a un update SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, transact-sql, microsoft-sql

tengo una consulta, digamos que tengo una tabla en SQL Server ordenada en base a la prioridad, con los siguientes campos:

```
| ID  | Prioridad| Nombre|
----------------------------
| 1   |   1      |  Nombre1
| 2   |   2      |  Nombre2
| 3   |   3      |  Nombre3
```

y digamos que actualizo el registro con ID 1 y ahora le asigno una prioridad de: 3, como puedo hacer para que ahora los otros registros actualicen su prioridad es decir: el ID 2, pase a prioridad 1 y el ID 3, pase a prioridad 2 (para que quede asi):

```
| ID  | Prioridad| Nombre|
----------------------------
| 2   |   1      |  Nombre2
| 3   |   2      |  Nombre3
| 1   |   3      |  Nombre1
```

Comment: Porque el 2 pasa a prioridad 1 y no es el 3 el que pasa a dicha prioridad?? Creo que lo mejor es que expliques la situación en que te encuentras, ya que puede que exista una mejor solución a tu problema

Comment: Esta ordenado de manera ascendente y siguiendo el orden (de la tabla de ejemplo) el 2 iría antes que el 3 por su prioridad

Comment: Es un problema interesante, has probado algo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El detalle es que con cada cambio a una fila necesitas actualizar todas las filas. Para hacer eso, podemos usar la función `ROW_NUMBER()`. Sin embargo, al asignar la nueva prioridad es importante saber si irá antes o después de la fila que ya tiene esa prioridad. Lo lógico es que si cambia a una prioridad más alta, las otras prioridades cambien a una prioridad más baja, y viceversa.

Para hacer las pruebas, vamos a crear la tabla y datos de prueba.

```
CREATE TABLE Prioridades(
    ID  int,
    Prioridad   int,
    Nombre      varchar(100)
);
INSERT INTO Prioridades
VALUES
( 1, 1, 'Nombre1'),
( 2, 2, 'Nombre2'),
( 3, 3, 'Nombre3');


SELECT *
FROM Prioridades;
```

Con eso, vamos a simular los parámetros y generamos el UPDATE con un CTE. La ventaja de usar un CTE es que se puede actualizar directamente y actualiza a la tabla, además de que podemos usar funciones de ordenamiento.

```
DECLARE @ID int = 1,
        @NuevaPrioridad int = 3;

WITH ctePrioridades AS(
    SELECT ID, 
        Prioridad,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY  CASE WHEN Id = @ID AND Prioridad < @NuevaPrioridad THEN @NuevaPrioridad + .1
                                          WHEN Id = @ID AND Prioridad > @NuevaPrioridad THEN @NuevaPrioridad - .1
                                          ELSE Prioridad END) NuevaPrioridad,
        Nombre
    FROM Prioridades
)
UPDATE ctePrioridades SET
    Prioridad = NuevaPrioridad

SELECT *
FROM Prioridades;
```

Sin Embargo, es probable que tengas unos rangos muy extensos y prefieras actualizar menos filas. Existe otra opción que requiere una lectura adicional a la tabla pero que podría compensarse con menos escritura. En ese caso utilizamos una variable para obtener la prioridad actual y generar un rango de filas a actualizar.

```
DECLARE @ID int = 1, --Mismos parámetros
        @NuevaPrioridad int = 3;

DECLARE @Prioridad int;

SELECT @Prioridad = Prioridad
FROM Prioridades
WHERE ID = @ID;

IF @Prioridad < @NuevaPrioridad 
    UPDATE P  SET
        Prioridad = CASE WHEN ID= @ID THEN @NuevaPrioridad ELSE Prioridad - 1 END
    FROM Prioridades P
    WHERE Prioridad BETWEEN @Prioridad AND @NuevaPrioridad;
ELSE
    UPDATE P  SET
        Prioridad = CASE WHEN ID= @ID THEN @NuevaPrioridad ELSE Prioridad + 1 END
    FROM Prioridades P
    WHERE Prioridad BETWEEN @NuevaPrioridad AND @Prioridad;

SELECT *
FROM Prioridades;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu ejemplo me ayudo!

Answer (score 1):

Por ejemplo...

Si tuviéramos un campo para cálculos temporales que permitiera decimales y hacemos que su valor sea el mismo que su prioridad para cada registro, cuando queramos asignar a un registro una posición, le pondríamos en ese campo temporal la misma prioridad menos 0.5

```
Temporal = nueva_prioridad - 0,5
```

Luego reordenamos de nuevo por el valor temporal y reasignamos las prioridades de los registros que se encuentren entre los dos valores de prioridad del registro modificado (el valor antiguo y el nuevo).

Según tu ejemplo:

Si a 1 le asignamos 3, le ponemos 2.5. Reordenamos y tenemos primero a 2, después a 3 y por último a 1.

Si quisiéramos subir 2 a prioridad 1, le asignamos 0.5 y reordenamos, quedando 2 primero, 1 segundo y 3 tercero.

Y así...

Imagino que hay muchas otras formas de enfocar y solucionar este algoritmo. Esta sería una de ellas.

Espero que te sirva.

Nota: tras cada reordenación volvemos a aaignar a temporal el valor acrualizado de prioridad, volviendo a ser enteros todos de nuevo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ejemplo.